# How does the stack multiply a 32 byte number with a 1 byte number?

Tags: evm, opcode, stack

I was looking at an example of the multiply opcode(MUL) on the website [www.evm.codes](http://www.evm.codes) and noticed it multiplied:

> 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF x 2

resulting in the output:

> 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE

how is this possible if the largest possible size of a word on the stack is 32 bytes??

Answer (score 1):

That is precisely because you have only 32 bytes, and the EVM manages overflows, removing the most significant bits in the result.

The multiply operation is just an add operation you do multiple times.

To sum bytes, you can work the same way with decimals: add the rightmost numbers first, write the sum, and carry the remainder.

So when you want to do `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE * 2 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE + 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE` you start from the rightmost byte:

`0xFF * 2 = 0xFF + 0xFF = 0x01FE` so the result is `0xFE` with `0x01` remainder.

Now, you need to carry that `0x01` for all the other sum operations that are all the same:

`0xFF * 2 = 0xFF + 0xFF = 0x01FE + 1 previous remainder = 0x01FF` so the result is `0xFF` with `0x01` remainder

Repeat that for 32 times, and now you have 33 bytes:

`0x01FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE`

But you can only deal with 32 bytes, not 33, so you lose the first byte, `0x01` and the final result is

`0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE`